# What's the difference between core data, essential data and sample data in hybris?

Tags: web-services, import, sap-commerce-cloud

In the hybris wiki trails, there is mention of core data vs. essential data vs. sample data.  What is the difference between these three types of data?

Ordinarily, I would assume that sample data is illustrative gobbledygook data created to populate the example apparel and electronics storefronts.  However, the [wiki trails](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/tr52/Customize+Initialization+Process+-+System+Setup+Classes) suggest that core data is for non-store specific data and the sample data is for store specific data.

On the same page, the wiki states that core data contains cockpit and catalog definitions, email templates, CMS layout, and site definitions (countries and user groups impex are included in this as well).  This seems rather store specific to me.  Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I have an explanation. Actually a lot of this is down to arbitrary decisions I made on separating data between `acceleratorcore` and `acceleratorsampledata` extensions as part of the Accelerator in 4.5 (later these had y- prefix added).

Essential and Project Data are two sets of data that are used within hybris' `init/update` process. These steps are controlled for each extension via particular Annotations on classes and methods.

Core vs Sample data is more about if I thought the impex file, or lines, were specific to the sample store or were more general. You will notice your `CoreSystemSetup` has both essential and `projectdata` steps.

Lots of work has happened in various continents since then, so, like much of hybris now, its a bit of a mess.

There are a few fun bugs related to hybris making certain things part of `essentialdata`. But these are in the platform not something I can fix without complaining to various people etc.

To confuse matters further, there is the `yacceleratorinitialdata` extension. This extension was a way I hoped to make projects easier, by giving some impex `skeletons` for new sites and stores. This would be generated for you during `modulegen`. It has rotted heavily though since release, now very out of date.

Comment: How much of this answer is still true in 2018?

Answer (score 1):

For a better explanation, take a look at [this answer from answers.sap.com](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12764283/definitions-of-coredata-essentialdata-projectdata.html).

Answer (score -3):

`Hybris` imports two types of data on `initialization` and `update` processes; first is essentialdata and other one is projectdata.
Essentialdata is the coredata setup which is mandatory and will import when you run `initialization` or `update`.
                                                                           sampledata  is your projectdata and it is not mandatory it will import when you select project while updating the system.

Comment: This doesn't really explain what the differences between project data, essential data, or core data are and why certain types of data belong to either essential, project or core.